# How to configure a channel in kepware to ingest dInt?

Tags: iot, opc-ua

As far as I have knowledge of the dInt, it is a signed 32-bit integer. On kepware, I don't see dInt in the dataType list to add the static tag. Hence, the question came, how does one configure Kepware channel to receive dInt tag?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Documentation on Siemens Datatypes and KepwareEX:

DINT == LONG

-

[image]

[image]